# Binding the raw request body in .net core without reading the request stream

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

One of our clients insist on sending a raw request body to our API (not json or xml) and as .net core doesn't support it by default, I used a similar idea with the one below:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("example/{path}")]
public async Task<string> ReadStringDataManual(string path)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
    {  
        return await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
}
```

However, in production we realised that the API throws the exception below on load.

```
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter:UnsafeOnCompletedInternal (method time = 1 ms, total time = 1 ms)
undefined(2011ms): await continuation
```

I am not sure if it's Kestrel related or not, but I believe it is because of the extensive I/O operation. I also tried a naive way - adding a parameter with `[FromBody]` attribute to the method signature, but no luck.

Is there any other option to read the raw request body without using stream reader?

Thanks.

Comment: what's  in the `path`? what format is it? why do you have to use stream?

Comment: Some time has passed but it seems like some improvements are coming to asp.net... take a look at this tweet from https://twitter.com/davidfowl/status/1480236116934467584

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to read the body of the request in `.NetCore` is a little bit different

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("example/{path}")]
public async Task<string> ReadStringDataManual(string path)
{

    ReadResult requestBodyInBytes = await Request.BodyReader.ReadAsync();
    Request.BodyReader.AdvanceTo(requestBodyInBytes.Buffer.Start, requestBodyInBytes.Buffer.End);
    string body = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(requestBodyInBytes.Buffer.FirstSpan);

    //Rest of the code

    return body;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've just had a chance to try it, it works fine, however `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionAbortedException: The connection was aborted by the application.
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Reading is already in progress.` is thrown. I've also tried `CancelPendingRead()` and `Complete()` methods on `Request.BodyReader`, but no luck. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Found the issue here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17840 , If you add `Request.BodyReader.AdvanceTo(test.Buffer.Start, test.Buffer.End);` before returning the result, it doesn't throw an exception. Please add it to your answer

Comment: @skynyrd can you have a look if thats what you meant?